# How to link fractional Fungible tokens to an NFT?

Tags: native

I have the following scenario. We will be minting NFT for assets and then would like to fractionalise them by minting fungible tokens.

I was wondering how to link together the NFT with the minted fungible tokens (say we issue 1000 tokens linked to an NFT) ? So that later when we want to correlated them, we can do this with confidence ? In other words currently one identifies the fungible tokens using information from token registry (and looking at policy id). But how would I know that this token is linked to an NFT (with a particular policy id).

One way could be to "manually include the original NFT policyid in the offchain token registry .." and then use that information to prove this connection.

Is there any other automated smarter ways to connect the fungible tokens to the NFT metadata ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably lookin for [CIP68](https://cips.cardano.org/cips/cip68/).

Using this metadata standard, you will be able to lock your NFT within the contact that would hold reference NFT for your fungible tokens.

It is worth to also mention [Fracada Il Primo](https://github.com/dcSpark/fracada-il-primo) by dcSpark.